# C# What is the easiest possibility to map/convert IEnumerable<Told> into another IEnumerable<Tnew> especially with EF

Tags: c#, linq

and  have the same properties. Sorry at the moment I have no example because I'm on the smartphone. I tried something like a selection with EF and LINQ and create a new object by setting the properties by mapping. but in the end I will also return an new IEnumerable.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: You are right! But sitting in the train with an empty laptop I just postet from my smartphone a simple question not expecting code solutions snippets or whatever. Nevertheless the given answers helped me to solve my problems.

Comment: No problem. Glad you figure out. See you around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use `.ConverAll` method:

```
   using System.Linq; // Need;

   internal class Program
   {
     private static void Main()
     {
       IEnumerable<TOld> told = new List<TOld> { new TOld { Name = "Name1", Age = 18 } };
       IEnumerable<TNew> tnew = told.ToList().ConvertAll(t => new TNew { Name = t.Name, Age = t.Age });

       foreach (var @new in tnew)
         Console.WriteLine(@new.Name);
     }
   }

   public class TOld
   {
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int Age { get; set; }
   }

   public class TNew
   {
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int Age { get; set; }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/). Below are 2 classes:

```
public class TOld {
   public string Prop1 { get; set; }
}

public class TNew {
   public string Prop1 { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code to tell AutoMapper how to map them. Using the code below you can map from `IEnumerable<TOld>` to `IEnumerable<TNew>` and vice versa:

```
// ReverseMap will do vice-versa mapping
Mapper.Initialize( x => x.CreateMap<TOld, TNew>().ReverseMap() );

IEnumerable<TOld> olds = new List<TOld> { new TOld { Prop1 = "TOld" } };

var news = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TNew>>( olds );
```